# Can we load data from json into Android High Charts

Tags: highcharts

High Charts JS supports loading data into Graph directly from JSON file, please check more detail here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#preprocess-data-using-json.

```
Highcharts.ajax({          
url: 'data.json',          
success: function(data) { 
           options.series[0].data = data;
            Highcharts.Chart('container', options);       
 } 
     });
```

Same can we achieve High charts for Android(https://www.highcharts.com/blog/products/android/)?

Trying to load json data directly to Graph.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `loadJSONOptions` method in the `HIChartView` class you just need to initialise it with a pre-serialised JSON to a java map.

Example of use:

```
HIChartView chartView = findViewById(R.id.hc);
chartView.loadJSONOptions(optionsMap);
```